# What does PS in ttyPS* stands for?

Tags: tty, devices, serial-port, uart

What does PS in ttyPS* stands for?

Where, in general, can I find the expanded names of devices under `/dev`?

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: Is it `/dev/ttyPS` or `/dev/ttyPSC*`?

Comment: If it's `/dev/ttyPS` and you use it on Zynq device it might mean *processing system*, at least this is what google shows https://www.google.com/search?q=zynq+ps but I haven't found an official explanation. The driver is implemented in `drivers/tty/serial/xilinx_uartps.c` in Linux kernel tree.

Comment: It also says *Processing System* in the official leaflet https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf so that's probably it.

Comment: I'm using Linux. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NOTE: This answer is assuming Linux

> Where, in general, can I find the expanded names of devices under /dev?

The devices have no "expanded names", but

```
udevadm info -a /dev/ttyPSx
```

will tell you a lot of interesting info about them.

If you don't have udev, you can get the type, major and minor of  the device, look it up via `/sys/dev`, and get the same information from the `/sys/devices/` files:

```
devinfo(){
    local p=$(readlink -f $(ls -l "$1" | sed 's@^\(.\)[^,]* \([0-9][0-9]*\), *\([0-9][0-9]*\).*@/sys/dev/\1*/\2:\3@'))
    while true; do
        case $p in
        /sys/devices/*)
           if [ -f "$p/uevent" ]; then
               echo ">>> $p"; cat "$p/uevent"; echo
           fi
           p=${p%/*};;
        *)
           break;;
        esac
    done
}

[prompt] devinfo /dev/ttyMT1
>>> /sys/devices/soc/11003000.apuart1/tty/ttyMT1
MAJOR=204
MINOR=210
DEVNAME=ttyMT1

>>> /sys/devices/soc/11003000.apuart1
DRIVER=mtk-uart
OF_NAME=apuart1
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/apuart1@11003000
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=mediatek,mt6735-uart
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
MODALIAS=of:Napuart1T<NULL>Cmediatek,mt6735-uart

>>> /sys/devices/soc
OF_NAME=soc
OF_FULLNAME=/soc
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=simple-bus
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
MODALIAS=of:NsocT<NULL>Csimple-bus
```

NB: Not all linux systems have usable `stat`, `awk` or even `sed` programs. This kludge is something that seems to work on some linux devices, like my desktop, router, phone and dashcam. In older androids, `sed` is a broken POS which isn't even able to cope with `echo pee | sed s/e/a/` (it will print `papee`).